# Xcode Server - Xcode 9 - Uses An Old Provisioning Profile

Tags: provisioning-profile, codesign, xcode-bots, xcode-server

Xcode archives successfully using the latest - *and correct* - provisioning profile.

However, the Bots configured in Xcode Server still use an older profile.

This can be seen if one authenticates as `xcodeserver` user and navigates to `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`.

Running `security cms -D -i myuuid.mobileprovision` confirms this.

Having tried reconfiguring a new Bot, restarting Xcode Server, deleting the old profile, and so on, nothing works.

How can we help Xcode 9 ***Server*** do what it promised, and use the latest provisioning profile from the Apple Provisioning Portal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dirty hack will work. This is assuming Xcode will correctly Archive using the correct profile. Unarchived the resulting `.app` file, then rename the `embedded.mobileprovision` file according to it's UUID, e.g.

`myuuid.mobileprovision`

Next, copy `myuuid.mobileprovision` to the `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles` folder.

Identify any older profiles linked to the same bundle identifier and delete. To play it safe, consider moving temporarily to `~/Desktop`.

Finally, integrate the Bot, unarchive the resulting `.app`., and inspect to confirm creation expiry date, UUID, and UDID array are all as expected:

`security cms -D -i embedded.mobileprovision`

Comment: solution to underlying issue of why Xcode Server fails to update would be much appreciated.

Comment: deleting also seems to force a new download.